# How can I get 3 letter day of week and 3 letter month using vanilla JavaScirpt Date object?

Tags: javascript, date

I need to get "Jun" for "June" and "Mon" for "Monday". The problem is looking up in an object of english words doesn't work if user has their language set to anything other than English.

```
export const shortDate = (str: any) => {
    const d = new Date(str);
    const dateString =
        daysOfWeek[d.getDay()].toUpperCase() +
        ', ' +
        shortMonths[d.getMonth()] +
        ' ' +
        d.getDate() +
        nth(d.getDate());

    return dateString;
};
```

I need to get rid of the `shortMonths` object and the `dayOfWeek` since this will be different when user is not English speaker.

Comment: This is what [Intl.DateTimeFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat) is for.

Comment: See [`Date.prototype.toLocaleString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString). Use `d.toLocaleString("en-US", { weekday: "short" })` and `d.toLocaleString("en-US", { month: "short" })`.

Answer (score 3):

Check out [Intl.DateTimeFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat):

```js
var date = new Date();

var options = { weekday: 'short', month: 'short' };
console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', options).format(date));
```

Or as [Sebastian points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71474087/how-can-i-get-3-letter-day-of-week-and-3-letter-month-using-vanilla-javascirpt-d/71474127#comment126330301_71474087) above, `date.toLocaleString`:

```js
const date = new Date()

console.log(date.toLocaleString('en-US', { weekday: 'short' }))
console.log(date.toLocaleString('en-US', { month: 'short' }))
```